# Mysql define variable by AS or direct

Tags: mysql, variables

What's the difference between these 2 queries?

```
select pc.* from payment_coupon pc
select pc.* from payment_coupon AS pc
```

Comment: There is no difference. They are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just one word: Readability.

Using `AS` is optional, like described [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).

Answer (score -1):

using `AS` for column name is  **mandatory** , for table name u just write alias with a space

`AS` is **optional** for tablename

Eg:

```
SELECT column1 AS c1 FROM table t // work
SELECT column1 c1 FROM table t // not works
SELECT column1 AS c1 FROM table AS t  //work
SELECT column1 c1 FROM table AS t //  not works
```

Comment: AS for a column name is not mandatory. Check out the manual: The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an identifier. However it is good practise to use the AS to clarify your SQL statement.